# Variable name from variable value

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create a variable with the name of a variables value?

Assuming we have a pair of values obtained by itr->name.GetString() and itr->value.GetString() in a loop. name contains the name of a data element and value the value.

E.g. itr->name.GetString() is pointing to "id" and itr->value.GetString() to 786 so I would like to create a variable like "int id=786"

Is there cheap trick to achieve this or is ELSE IF the only way?

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Why do you need to create variables with unknown names? How are you supposed to access them later on? Is there any reason or is it purely academical?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a json file wich contains data. In my case the data structure of the json file is known so I am able to assign the data obtained from the json file with ELSE IF. 
But during this the questions came to my mind what if there is an unexpected change in the json data structure. I asked my "rubberduck" and he responded with the question  above. And google did not answered that. So yes, the question is more academical ;)

Comment: Get a reputable JSON C++ library.  Or if not that, investigate how those libraries work without having to resort to doing anything as you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example

> E.g. itr->name.GetString() is pointing to "id" and itr->value.GetString() to 786 so I would like to create a variable like "int id=786"

naming variable name at runtime is not possible, but there is a workaround.

```
struct test
{
    string name;
    int value;
}

int main()
{
    test var;
    var.name = itr->name.GetString();
    var.value = itr->value.GetToInt32(); //Convert string to integer first
    return 0;
}
```

You get the idea

Comment: Thanx, the workaround does not fit. I just want to know if it is technical possible or not (whenever it has risks)

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is probably to use a `std::map<std::string, int> m;`.

You can then do things like

```
m[itr->name.GetString()] = std::stoi(itr->value.GetString());
```